# jQuery data() in window.load and document.ready, got undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Need to store some data in `window.load` and retrieve in `document.ready`:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() { // Store here
      $('img.storable').each(function() {
         $(this).data("key", "value");
         console.log($(this).data("key")); // Output: value
      };
   };

   $(document).ready(function() { // Retrieve here
      $('img.storable').each(function() {
         console.log($(this).data("key")); // Output: undefined!
      };
   };
</script>
```

Output in `document.ready` is *undefined*. Am I missing something about DOM events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` runs as soon as the DOM has loaded, but `$(window).load()` will not run until the DOM has loaded AND all dom resources have loaded (like images and CSS files and stuff). That means that `$(document).ready()` will run before you set the value.

Answer (score 2):

I think document ready happens before window.load ...
So it should be exactly the other way around

Just do a simple test:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('document ready');
});
$(window).load(function() {
   alert('window load');
});
```